# syntx err when using maven in build.gradle.kts

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, maven, jitpack

[image]

Whene I try using jitpack.io in android studio this error appear for me .

```
 plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.arzju.agah"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.arzju.agah"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
    
    
    dependencies {
        constraints {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
                because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
            }
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
                because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
            }
        }
        implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
        implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
        implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
        implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.0")
        implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.0")
        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
        implementation ("com.github.myketstore:myket-billing-client:1.6")
    }
```

**and this is error =>**

Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

this appear for line 38

so where have to use jitpack.io ?
I copy this code from official document but it doesn't work .

Comment: check setting build.gradle.kts

Comment: and check ur image line no 21

Comment: proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            ) that place remove last ")" this one